# Approach to exhaustively test Swift struct conformance to Equatable?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, struct

The title almost says it all. My project is in Swift 2.3. Ocassionaly a custom struct model object is introduced. For various reasons, this must conform to Equatable.

Let's for example have a struct with 6 different value-type variables, all from Swift standard library.

```
struct Address: Equatable {

    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let street: String
    let streetNumber: Int
    let city: String
    let countryCode: Int
}

func ==(lhs: Address, rhs: Address) -> Bool {

    return (
        lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName &&
        lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName &&
        lhs.street == rhs.street &&
        lhs.streetNumber == rhs.streetNumber &&
        lhs.city == rhs.city &&
        lhs.countryCode == rhs.countryCode)
}
```

What is the correct algorithm to ensure I will test **ALL** the combinations of (in)equality in my unit test?

Permutations/combinations? Perhaps something more programatic?

Comment: 1) You haven't shown your implementation of the `Comparable` protocol, so your question is currently unanswerable; 2) I'd be interested to see how you intend to implement the less-than operator for addresses; 3) Unless the number of combinations is small, you generally don't and shouldn't unit test *all* possible combinations of anything - at most you shouldn't need more than 7 legitimate test cases, here.

Comment: Ah..always confusing Equatable and Comparable...I need to fix that..as for the implementation, we've seen it all. I find it pointless to put it here plus the struct is just an example.

Comment: Also I strongly believe I SHOULD be testing all the combinations because the Equatable implementation is a prefect ooportunity for stupid mistakes or typos and the test might just not hit a wrong || or missed line.

Comment: It's not pointless. There are plenty of cases whether equality is defined by something other than a simple comparison of all the members. For instance, take two of your addresses. Does John Smith, 10 Acacia Avenue, Leeds, UK compare equal to Jane Smith, 10 Acacia Avenue, Leeds, UK, or does it not? It may be "just an example", but the "correct algorithm" depends on what you're doing. It can make the difference, for example, between having to test all combination of all the members, and not having to do that.

Comment: Ok in the case of example it is equal when each lhs member equals to each rhs member.

Comment: Then just have test cases for each combination. If you try to do it programmatically in some way, you're just shifting the risk of error from the tested code to the test code.

Comment: I added the implementation to avoid any chance of confusion. With number of member being >3 the nubmer all possible test cases gets out of hand quickly.

Comment: It's a perfect example. Your function makes six comparisons, so you need seven test cases. One where each of the six is different, and a seventh where they're all the same. Additional test cases add nothing, and they make it a real pain to make any changes to your struct later, because the testing code becomes ridiculous to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, exhaustively testing all the combinations is just a flat-out poor strategy. It's unnecessary, and serves only to make unit testing more troublesome and makes you less likely to do it well.

With a very simple equality function like this, there's a good case to be made that you don't need to test it at all. If you must test it, testing one case for equality, and one case for inequality, is good enough. If you want to really go crazy, you can have one test for equality, and six tests for inequality in each of your members.

It's better to write out the test cases individually and manually, because you should be able to have faith in the correctness of a unit test simply by looking at it. If you can't, then you can end up in the rather absurd position of having to unit test your unit tests.

However, if you really absolutely insist on doing things the wrong way and exhaustively testing every possible combination, then you can do so like this:

```
func makeAddressPair(sames: [Bool]) -> (Address, Address) {
    let firstName = ["John", sames[0] ? "John" : "Jane"]
    let secondName = ["Smith", sames[1] ? "Smith" : "Williams"]
    let street = ["Acacia Avenue", sames[2] ? "Acacia Avenue" : "Privet Close"]
    let streetNumber = [10, sames[3] ? 10 : 21]
    let city = ["Leeds", sames[4] ? "Leeds" : "Bolton"]
    let country = [1, sames[5] ? 1 : 2]

    return (Address(firstName: firstName[0], lastName: secondName[0], street: street[0],
                    streetNumber: streetNumber[0], city: city[0], countryCode: country[0]),
            Address(firstName: firstName[1], lastName: secondName[1], street: street[1],
                    streetNumber: streetNumber[1], city: city[1], countryCode: country[1]))

}

class AddressCompareTests: XCTestCase {

    func testAddressCompare() {
        var comparesEqual = 0
        var comparesInequal = 0

        for a in [true, false] {
            for b in [true, false] {
                for c in [true, false] {
                    for d in [true, false] {
                        for e in [true, false] {
                            for f in [true, false] {
                                let (first, second) = makeAddressPair(sames: [a, b, c, d, e, f])

                                if first == second {
                                    comparesEqual += 1
                                }
                                else {
                                    comparesInequal += 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(comparesEqual, 1)
        XCTAssertEqual(comparesInequal, 63)
    }

}
```

You have 2 ^ 6 = 64 possible combinations, because you have six members, and between two structs, each pair of members can be either equal, or not equal. Here we have a helper function to generate a pair of structs based on a list of which members should be equal between them, and a nested loop to generate all possible combinations of pairs. When you compare all the pairs, exactly one should compare equal, and exactly 63 should compare unequal, so those are the test conditions we assert, since at least then we have some kind of poor cousin to quality control over the correctness of our test.

If instead you tested two or seven cases manually, it would be much simpler, clearer, easier to read and verify, and would take fewer lines of code, than doing it this way.

Comment: I don't get what you need to test all 64 combinations. If it's to fail, 6 would also suffice. Can you give me a situation where the combo would fail, but the simple 6 test won't?

Comment: @Honey: As I say in my answer, I don't think you do need to test all 64 combinations. It is possible, though, with poorly chosen test data. For example, if you replaced the first `&&` with a `||`, and the first two fields in your test data were both different, then the simple 6 test would pass, but you'd get some incorrect equalities when you tested the full 64.

Comment: I get it now, I think the possibility of the error you mentioned is just as much as much as the other 6, or maybe slightly less, which makes it reasonable enough to have tested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a relative newbie on TDD but this what I have learned so far:

### Helper function

```
 func performNotEqualTestWithAddresssProperties(firstNameF: String, firstNameS: String, LastNameF: String, LastNameS: String, streetF: String, streetS: String streetNumberF: Int, streetNumberS: Int, cityF: String, cityS: String, countryCodeF : Int, countryCodeS : Int){
  let AddressFirst = Address(firstName: firstNameF, LastName:LastNameF, street: streetF, streetNumber: streetNumberF, city : cityF, countryCode: countryCodeF)
  let AddressSecond = Address(firstName: firstNameS, LastName:LastNameS, street: streetS, streetNumber: streetNumberS, city : cityS, countryCode: countryCodeS)

  XCTAssertNotEqual(AddressFirst, AddressSecond, "Addresses are not equal")

  // 'F' means first, 'S' means second, I just avoided to not have long lines
 // The helper function takes 2 sets of Addresses and Asserts if they ARE equal

    }
```

### actual test

```
 func testWhenAddressDiffers_SHouldNotBeEqual() {
performNotEqualTestWithAddresssProperties(firstNameF: "Earl", firstNameS: "Earl", LastNameF: "Grey", LastNameS: "Grey", streetF: "south", streetS: "south", streetNumberF: 23, streetNumberS: 23, cityF: "silicon valley", cityS: "silicon valley", countryCodeF: 24, countryCodeS: 29)

//write another and switch firstName,another and switch LastName, ...
```

Here I only tested `countryCode`. All other elements were the same.
to fully test your Address struct equality, each time you populate *all* properties of Address identical **except** for one. So basically you have to write this function 6 times.

You have 6 equalities to test. They are independent expressions and need to be treated independently. This is the best programmatic way I know of.

Comment: Writing it 6 (or N really) times is exactly what I want to avoid..plus I don't think it would be all possible combinations.

Comment: @EarlGrey Welcome to TDD. I'm learning TDD from [this](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/test-driven-ios-development-swift-3) book. I highly recommend. The author is [dasdom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/498796/dasdom).He's doing this way and based on my limited understanding of TDD so far. This is the best way. What you want is not possible. You have to test 6 independent expressions. If you ever found a better way be sure to let us know.

Comment: And I just started...there is definitely more cases than your 6.

Comment: @EarlGrey What cases do you mean? And what are the !!!!! suppose to mean?